# Why is transaction gone from Ember Data?

Tags: ember-data

From the [latest update](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#transaction-is-gone-save-individual-records) in September 2013, "transaction is gone" from Ember Data. Instead, records are saved individually.  Unlike other changes, this is not just simply making Ember Data syntax easier.

So I wonder, what are the reasons that the Ember Data team got rid of transactions?

Answer (score 1):

I think this was done to make it easier to work with Ember Data.  The old way involved a coding a lot of explicit transaction management, even for fairly simple changes.  The new way is much cleaner for simple use cases, and you can still batch changes, as mentioned in the TRANSITION document.

Old way: (Assuming you already have a live object in the `model` var.)

```
var transaction = this.get('store').transaction();
transaction.add(model);
transaction.commit();
```

New way:

```
model.save();
```

Comment: does it mean rollbacks are also gone?

Comment: Nope, rollbacks are still there.  You just call it on the model.  `model.rollback();`